# Using clearInterval in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple JavaScript Timer. Firstly, here's my code that I'm working with:

```
//Variables used for the timer
var timer = "waiting",
    seconds = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    extraFill1 = "",
    extraFill2 = "";

//Check whether to start or stop the timer
function toggleClock() {
    if (timer === "waiting") {
        setInterval(start, 1000);
        timer = "executing";
        document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "Stop";
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(start);
        timer = "waiting";
        document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "Start";
    }   
}

//Increment seconds and display correctly
function start() {
    seconds++;

    //Add a leading zero for 1 digit numbers (seconds)
    if (seconds < 10 || seconds === 60) {
        extraFill1 = "0";
    }
    else {
        extraFill1 = "";
    }

    //Increment minute when seconds reaches 60
    if (seconds === 60) {
        minutes += 1;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    //Add a leading zero for 1 digit numbers (minutes)
    if (minutes < 10) {
        extraFill2 = "0";
    }
    else {
        extraFill2 = "";
    }

    //display results
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = extraFill2 + minutes + ":" + extraFill1 + seconds;
}
```

In my first function `toggleClock()`, I have stated that if `timer !== waiting`, then we do clearInterval(start). I would like to `clearInterval(start)` if `timer === "executing`. This does not work (which I think is because it has a local scope?). To solve this, I attempted writing:

```
var myTimer = setInterval(start, 1000);
```

I planned on calling myTimer when I wanted to start the timer. Instead, the interval kicks off as soon as the page is loaded (and the variable is declared).

How might I set an interval of a function (on button click) with the ability to stop/clear the interval (by pressing the same button) later?

Comment: `clearInterval` expects to be passed the **ID** of the interval you want to stop, not a function. Please read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass to `clearInterval` the *result* of your call to `setInterval` earlier; you don't pass a function to `clearInterval`, you pass it the `intervalID`. For example:

```
let clockInterval;
function toggleClock() {
  if (timer === "waiting") {
    clockInterval = setInterval(start, 1000);
    timer = "executing";
    document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "Stop";
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(clockInterval);
    timer = "waiting";
    document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "Start";
  }   
}
```

Comment: You code makes sense but your explanation does not: what do you mean by "..the result of your call.. "? Do you mean reassigning the variable equal to the interval?

Comment: The result of calling `setInterval` is an intervalID - so, just assign that to a variable that you can call `clearInterval` with later.